# Can I make Wordpress searchbar filter to give only articles from blog and not from woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, blogs, searchbar

When using the searchbar in the "news" page of my Wordpress, it displays posts from the blog but also posts that are products from Woocommerce, or other pages / content. I would like it to display only blog posts.

I haven't found any solution yet. Also, Wordpress won't let me update the php files of the theme, so I think I need on-site settings / plugins.

Here is the news page : https://champagne-oudart.com/actualites/
The client wanted the news categories to be years.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use a plugin like Relevanssi https://wordpress.org/plugins/relevanssi/

It enables you to limit/control the search in many ways, also the one you asked for, and it's very simple to handle.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```html
function modify_search_query( $query ) {
    // Make sure this isn't the admin or is the main query
    if( is_admin() || ! $query->is_main_query() ) {
      return;
    }
  
    // Make sure this isn't the WooCommerce product search form
    if( isset($_GET['post_type']) && ($_GET['post_type'] == 'product') ) {
      return;
    }
  
    if( $query->is_search() ) {
      $in_search_post_types = get_post_types( array( 'exclude_from_search' => false ) );
  
      // The post types you're removing (example: 'product' and 'page')
      $post_types_to_remove = array( 'product', 'page' );
  
      foreach( $post_types_to_remove as $post_type_to_remove ) {
        if( is_array( $in_search_post_types ) && in_array( $post_type_to_remove, $in_search_post_types ) ) {
          unset( $in_search_post_types[ $post_type_to_remove ] );
          $query->set( 'post_type', $in_search_post_types );
        }
      }
    }
  
  }
  add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'modify_search_query' );
```

add these lines to your functions.php

Comment: This is great, thanks! I've modified the file via FileZilla. Yet now I only get "no results found". I'm not sure what I need to modify in your php. Any idea?

Comment: Also, I get this Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /homepages/18/d777401215/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Champagneoudart/wp-content/themes/salient/functions.php:1) in /homepages/18/d777401215/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Champagneoudart/wp-admin/includes/misc.php on line 1196
on the top of my back-office pages. And the 'customize' panel won't let me edit the css.

Comment: Sorry to keep on adding, but I also get this on one of my pages : Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /homepages/18/d777401215/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Champagneoudart/wp-content/themes/salient/functions.php:1) in /homepages/18/d777401215/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Champagneoudart/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1251
I have already checked the functions.php opening and closing tags, there are no extra spaces there.

Comment: remove comments and check, check warning source through console